# python change powershell curren session env variable

Tags: python, powershell

What I want is:

1. opened a powershell command line
2. run a "script.py" file. So that add a $env:aa=bb env variable.
3. I run $env:aa in current powershell command line. Can print bb rightly.

More specific.

I have a script that let user select the java home in the prompt list, and set the JAVA_HOME variable(in system widely). It worked after user reopen the powershell. But I want insert the $JAVA_HOME/bin in front of the $env:path in current session. So the choice can effect immediately.

How the script.py like?

Comment: You can't trivially change the env block in the parent process from a child process. You _can_ make the python process _output_ something and then create/set a bunch of environment variables based on that output in PowerShell if you want to. Can you describe your use case in more detail?

Comment: Hello, thanks for youre replay. I have already update the describe.

Comment: And `script.py` does what exactly? Reads the info from a file? Tries to reads machine-wide env variables? PowerShell could do that directly...

Comment: It change the $JAVA_HOME in by `command = ['powershell', '-Command', f'[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("{key}", "{value}", "User")']
    subprocess.run(command)
`
But it only worked after repoen the powershell...

Comment: Cut out the `python` and `powershell` child processes and just run `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("key", "value", "User")` directly in the first powershell instance. To replicate in the current process without reopening, do: `$env:key = "value"` as well